# Drupal view preview links to origial content, but not full content

Tags: views, theming, entities

My view presents a preview of truncated articles.  When the "title" field is clicked, you are brought to a "full content" page of that preview.  But the "full content only shows the title and body.  I need to also show the full "body image."